# Which contacts have my application installed?

Tags: android, contacts

I'm building a small app for messaging (in some way a bit similar to 'WhatsApp' or 'Viber'). WhatsApp and Viber show you contacts that are from your contact list and have an account with them. so my question is how to sync?

For now, I have database which stores all users using the application and their phone number.
Do I need to run a query for each contact in my phone in order to find it in the database?
It looks a lot of queries for every sync request.

What is the efficient way in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have both sets of data as database tables, then can't you just join on some attribute like 'Full Name' and the resulting table will be all people in your contacts list with the app installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can display contacts in your app that are just pulled from the contact list on the phone. Using LoadManager you can get a contact list that is synced with the phone list.

Check out these links for more info

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html
https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Comment: But how can I know which one of the contacts I've just pulled from the phone have my application installed? I have to run a query for each one of them and look for them in the 'Users' table, if a contact exist in the 'Users' table I know he have the app installed?
There is no other way to do this which requires less queries?

Comment: You have the phone numbers in this Users table right? You can get the numbers in a list and use the list in a sql query

Comment: You will need a backend server. So retrieve the phone number list in the app, send it to the server, check which users are registered on database and return that list.